# Is everything in the Talmud considered Jewish Law?

Tags: halacha, talmud-gemara

Is everything in the Talmud considered Jewish Law? Can something be in the Talmud but not be considered Halacha?

Comment: Aside from what Meir brings, the Talmud contains halachic rulings and opinions that are *valid* halacha but not the *accepted* halacha.  Nobody today holds according to these opinions and it is not permitted to go back and decide to hold like them, but they are halacha nonetheless.  Everything in the Talmud is true on one or more levels.

Comment: @yoel I don't think all Rishonim would agree to that, nor do I suspect you think all Rishonim would agree to that. Plus many of your "levels" of truth are definitely not what the OP means by truth.

Comment: @DoubleAA in a machlokes rishonim they're both also true on one or more levels. :)  At any rate my intention was to express to OP that there is nothing in Talmud that we "reject".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many things in theTalmud that are not Halacha, like Agadeta (stories/parables) and interpretations of of Pesukim not relevant to Halacha.

Comment: Not to mention discussions of medicinal treatments that may occasionally have been intended non-literally, but at the literal level, Rabbi Hai Gaon wrote that the rabbis of the Talmud were working with the best medical knowledge at their time, while we are obligated to use the best medical knowledge of our time.

Comment: @Shalom or Tosfos say things that might have worked then don't work now.

Comment: In addition, the Talmud often records the divergent opinions of the rabbis on various issues. Then the text, itself, or a codifier like the Shulchan Aruch or the Rambam, following particular rules, states whom the halacha is decided. The other opinions, though extant, are not halacha. If in our every day life we hold like beit hillel, we don't hold like beit shamai, but their opinion is in the Talmud.

Comment: @yoel right which may be true for certain things, but it's good to note that hai gaon was living back then and there and already noted the problems. So tosfos's answer can't work for everything.